# Google maps api tracking device

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Basically, i'm trying to track my position every time I move.

Ive managed to get the follwing code working with the `'click'` listener event, just to test it, I'm just not sure what and how i'd use the correct event listener on the fly:

```
function mapRoute(showPosition3, position){



var routeCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(53.388639, -1.4785248000000002)];



  var polyOptions = {
    path: routeCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  }

 flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);

 flightPath.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);

}


/**
 * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
 * @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
 */
function addLatLng(event) {

  var path = flightPath.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear
  path.push(event.latLng);

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [geolocation.watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation)

Comment: Is it compatible with chrome and safari and ie?

Comment: @ Tezro Solutions: yes, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few details involved with this. If you'd rather not code your own from scratch, you can use the [GeolocationMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/) which is part of the [Google Maps API v3 Utility Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). It handles a lot of the small details for you. Since it is open source, you can also modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have kind of got a base already for which to work on and ive also worked out how to implement the above code. I simply used the headed_change event and it works find now.